# My world has a huge void gap. How do I fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have this huge gap in my world. I was just starting to get things going with the FTB mod so please tell me this is easy to fix.

[image: minecraft bug]

When I enter it I can move forward very slowly. I did not move in all the way but just a bit with SHIFT and took me some time to get out of it. I cannot build in it either. For further experimentation, I need to bring my Efficiency IV, Unbreakable III, and Fortune II diamond pickaxe to safety first, which is another reason I want this world fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a standard problem in Minecraft, and a known bug.

Fix it by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to refresh your chunks, or failing that, logging out and back in again.

Comment: How the creeper didn't i find that using google? I searched on gap, world bug, corrupt, etc. Anyway I tried reloading MC and almost got a hart attack since it failed loading on creating terrain and quit without warning.